# how to change point light color from geo nodes using drivers

Tags: geometry-nodes, drivers, simulation-nodes

I have this geo nodes setup where a point light is instanced in the middle of explosion i want  this hue slider to somehow affect the Color or hue of point light in EEVEE

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello well i reframed my question  i think i can control the emission of point light with drivers but don;t know about the color

Comment: Ah okay, now I see. So if you know how to drive the emission (strength I guess?), you can drive the color or hue as well in _Cycles_, there you can use shader nodes for the light... unfortunately I have no idea how to do this in _EEVEE_.